# Do you have to refrigerate leftover grilled corn-on-the-cob?

Tags: corn

I'm not familiar with any method for this. Usually it's all gone!  When grilling the other night, I made way too much food and had lots of leftovers.  Do I need to refrigerate the ears of corn that are already grilled?  Before I put them on the grill I put butter on them, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you should.  It does loose a little bit in reheating (we frequently use a microwave the second time around, if it's still on the cob), but it's fine for a few days in the fridge.

If you made excessive amounts, you might also consider removing it from the cob, bagging it, and freezing the kernels 'til you need them.  You can throw it into soups, salsa, pot pies, etc.

You can also freeze the stripped cobs to save for the next time you're making stock.

Comment: So, after a few too many days where there was corn served, and leftovers.  Corn seemed to be okay if left out overnight, but 2 or three days at room temp and it was growing mold.  Corn in the fridge (wrapped in foil or in an airtight container) easily went a week or two without molding.  Of course, the local climate would affect how quickly it went off if not in the fridge.  ... oh, and NONE of these were buttered.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably be best served refrigerating it. Heating the corn could likely compromise the structural integrity of the kernels (grilling probably boosts that probability), leaving their moist flesh exposed to air, thereby creating an environment for pathogens to grow. Just remove the kernels from the cob with a knife, and put them in a container. You can keep them in the refrigerator or freezer after that.

With my leftover corn on the cob, I like doing a quick saute with butter and black pepper. But there are plenty of other uses, as well (soups, cornbread, etc.).