# How long does cooked corn on the cob keep in the fridge?

Tags: refrigerator, corn

There's a question [here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/18432/do-you-have-to-refrigerate-leftover-grilled-corn-on-the-cob) that indicates the cooked corn on the cob should be refrigerated, but doesn't indicate how long it will stay good for.

Does it make a difference whether the corn on the cob was grilled or boiled initially?

Comment: Hi and welcome - this is generally covered by our overall answer for storage questions here: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21068/how-long-can-i-store-a-food-in-the-pantry-refrigerator-or-freezer It doesn't look like corn is specifically covered under the tables, but there are many more details on the linked StillTasty site, specifically here: https://www.stilltasty.com/fooditems/index/16964

Comment: @logophobe : nope, that's for raw corn.  For cooked see https://stilltasty.com/fooditems/index/16962 .  (and when we started, this was a large percentage of our questions, rather than shunt everyone off to a single incomplete answer)